# BaseX currently open error - BXDB0007

Tags: transactions, basex

I am using the c basex-api to send an xquery command to my BaseX server. This query updates an xml tag. If I have the same DB open in the BaseX GUI, I get the error "[bxerr:BXDB0007] Database 'site-1' is currently opened by another process."

I can't find much help on this error online. There's a lot of information on Transaction management, and I thought that BaseX could handle multiple sessions at the same time. Certainly most Databases can. So, why do I get an error when the GUI is open? Incidentally, I'm only wishing to view data on the GUI read-only.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Concurrent Operations](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Startup#Concurrent_Operations) section in the docs. The GUI and standalone modes do not interact with the server, they operate directly on the database files.